# No data received from NEO6M after using HardwareSerial in ESP32CAM w/ USB

Tags: esp32

I am experiencing an error when fetching data from NEO6M through ESP32 CAM w/ USB. I want to fetch the NEO6M data correctly and use TinyGPS++ to format the received data into an understandable one. Can anyone lend me assistance for making this code works?

```
// libraries
#include "TinyGPS++.h"
#include "TimeLib.h"

HardwareSerial NEO6M(1); // tx, rx

// constants
#define CHAR_NUM 110
#define timeOffset 28800 // UTC-8

// variables
char latitude[11];
char longitude[11];
char Date[] = "00/00";
char Time[] = "00:00";
byte last_second, Second, Minute, Hour, Day, Month;
int Year;
 
// texts
char nameText[CHAR_NUM], alcoholLevelText[CHAR_NUM], locationText[CHAR_NUM], dateTimeText[CHAR_NUM];

// tinygps++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

void setup() {
  // serial monitor setup
  Serial.begin(9600);
  NEO6M.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, 14, 16); // TX/RX

  // check if serial monitor is available
  if (Serial.available()>0) {
    Serial.println("Serial monitor is available");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Serial monitor is not available!");
  }
  
}

void loop() {
  useNEO6M();
  
  Serial.println(locationText);
  Serial.println(dateTimeText);

  snprintf(locationText, sizeof(locationText), "Location: %s,%s",
           latitude, longitude);
  snprintf(dateTimeText, sizeof(dateTimeText), "Date: %s\nTime: %s",
           Date, Time);
           
  delay(1000);
}

void useNEO6M() {
  char latitudeTemp[11];
  char longitudeTemp[11];
  
  while (NEO6M.available() > 0) {
      gps.encode(NEO6M.read());
      Serial.println(latitudeTemp);
      dtostrf(gps.location.lat(), 9, 6, latitudeTemp);
      dtostrf(gps.location.lng(), 9, 6, longitudeTemp);

      if (gps.time.isValid()) {
        Second = gps.time.second();
        Minute = gps.time.minute();
        Hour = gps.time.hour();
      }

      if (gps.date.isValid()) {
        Day = gps.date.day() + 1;
        Month = gps.date.month();
        Year = gps.date.year();
      }
      
      if (last_second != gps.time.second()) {
        last_second = gps.time.second();

        setTime(Hour, Minute, Second, Day, Month, Year);

        adjustTime(timeOffset);
    
        changeLatitude(latitudeTemp);
        changeLongitude(longitudeTemp);
        changeTime();
        changeDate();
      }
      
  }
  
}
```

This is my output code:
[image]

As you can see, the program cannot retrieve the data from NEO6M GPS

Comment: I seem to recall that on some boards you need to first 'switch on' the GPS chip by enabling it to receive power via the power control chip (AXP); could that be the issue? It looks like you're not getting any data at all from the chip. However, even when enabled, it might take some time to find satellites and actually receive any data.

Comment: Hi, I tested the module on Arduino Uno R3 using SoftwareSerial, and there are no issues. I want to use the same program on ESP32 CAM w/USB, and there is no SoftwareSerial. Upon browsing the forum, I tried using HardwareSerial, but I encountered issues when collecting data from NEO6M GPS module.